# Combo Box / Context Menu strange behaviour (invisible)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, user-interface, .net-4.0

I have written an application in WPF/VB.net and have been testing it on a few different computers.

I have never experienced this issue on my development machine but one of my test machines has a strange issue where combo box lists and context menus are invisible.

The objects are there and you can select items from them but they are not being drawn.

I am scratching my head with this and have been searching for evidence of similar issues online but not really found anything.

I would like to completely rule out that this is a programming issue before going down the route of pointing the blame at any particular hardware my company is using.

I am using one click deployment and have transparency enabled on my windows.

This is an intermittent problem and restarting the PC will fix the issue. Restarting the application does not make the issue go away.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed by forcing software rendering on windows XP within the App.

This was done by adding the following line to application start up.

```
RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = System.Windows.Interop.RenderMode.SoftwareOnly
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that the machine you have problems with has the correct .net framework loaded. If you are using any other products such as Silverlight then check versions.

Comment: The application was building .net4 and I noticed the machine in question only had the client profile installed. So I have rebuilt the application using the client profile to see if that makes any difference. Thanks.

Comment: The machines now have identical .net updates and the problem is still occurring. I tested another WPF application on the same machine and combo boxes did work at the same time that the combo boxes had invisible lists on the first App.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm out of ideas why this could be happening.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just wanted the throw the question out there to see if I might have missed something before looking at hardware. It looks like we have around 3 different models of graphics card across 150 computers so That's what I am going to look at next.